VS Code Already updated but still show notification circle to download update
Ubuntu 24.04
below is from vs code > Help > About
Version: 1.92.1
Commit: eaa41d57266683296de7d118f574d0c2652e1fc4
Date: 2024-08-07T20:16:39.455Z
Electron: 30.1.2
ElectronBuildId: 9870757
Chromium: 124.0.6367.243
Node.js: 20.14.0
V8: 12.4.254.20-electron.0
OS: Linux x64 6.8.0-40-generic


whenever start VS Code it show notification to download Update and when click on it, it opens vs code download page and download the .deb package.
why this is occuring while VS code is already updated and on latest verison, although if its not updated; how can we make sure it automatically update because if new update I have to export the profile and seetings every time.
